# На чем же лучше писать API или VCL?

Tags: delphi, opengl, vcl

Начал учить OpenGl, но сразу же возникли раздумья, в которых лучше посоветоваться с более опытными людьми, поэтому и обращаюсь сюда.

Скачал книгу М.Краснова "OpenGl графика в проектах Delphi" (да, да, я хочу писать на Delphi) и там он говорит, что лучше не использовать VCL, а писать на API из-за тяжести VCL.

Я запустил приложение, рисующее обычный квадрат на VCL и оно весило порядка 900 кб, а приложение, рисующее круг и квадрат на API весило 29кб!

Почему я задаю сей вопрос? Да потому, что мне не нравится c-шный непонятный код, который очень похож на API. Так вот, на чем же лучше писать API или VCL? А также второй вопрос: какие еще книги можете посоветовать для изучения OpenGl на Delphi?

P.S. всем спасибо, остановлюсь пока что на VCL, а в будущем, может быть, и перейду) Только просьба: киньте, пожалуйста, литературы какой-нибудь, чтобы хоть выбор был)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По моему вы что-то путаете. VCL не предоставляет ничего для OpenGL. Рисование круга и квадрата - совсем не задача для OpenGL. Так что VCL vs WinAPI вообще никак не связан с OpenGL.

Что же до холиварно-подобной темы VCL vs WinAPI: вы сами ответили на свой вопрос: разница в весе очевидна. С недавних пор также VCL стала плохо поддерживаться, а WinAPI по крайней мере по прежнему тестируется мягкими.

VCL хороша для написания программ с кнопочками, всякие корпоративные приложения и т.п. Для графики не очень годится в принципе. Только лишний вес, а пользы абсолютно никакой. Да ещё потери в производительности.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем вопросе уже и содержится ответ. К примеру, как Вам легче создать новое окно - VCL `form := TForm1.Create(self)` или WinAPI `CreateWindow` (уже не помню)? У каждого подхода свои сторонники и противники. Но по-моему, зачем Вам ломать голову с С-подобным кодом, если привыкли к VCL, тем более сэкономите уйму времени. А "тяжеловесность" для параметров современных компов в данном случае не особо существенна. Хотя WinAPI все же дает большее представление о работе программ, да и вдруг придумаете шедевр, который не реализован в VCL.